# Xamarin Forms Best way to run a background thread

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a question. I am building an app that collects stock market prices, but now the most important part is where I do a call every x seconds to get the new price. The variable of the price is located in the App.xaml.cs, so it is global for every page, but now I need to update it with the following line every 3 seconds: `CoinList = await RestService.GetCoins();`

The function must be async because the whole RestService is async!

I already found something like this:

```
var minutes = TimeSpan.FromMinutes (3); 

Device.StartTimer (minutes, () => {

    // call your method to check for notifications here

    // Returning true means you want to repeat this timer
    return true;
});
```

But I don't know if this is the best way to do it and where I should put it, because it is the most essential part of my app!

Any suggestions?

Comment: So, you're looking for a timer, right?

Comment: I think so, I need to update a variable every 3 seconds by running a Task

Comment: Yes, last time I checked (2 years ago), timer functionality was very limited. If your example is newer, it it's a better fit Do note you can make it async by: `Device.StartTimer (minutes, async () => {` Note2: it's equivalent to `async void`, that has some down sides.

Comment: But this is the best way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap the async method into a `Task.Run`, check the code below .

```
Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), () =>
{
  Task.Run(async () =>
  {
    CoinList = await RestService.GetCoins();
  });
  return true;
});
```

Answer (score 5):

This is one case where would recommend `async void` over a non-awaited `Task.Run`, because not awaiting the `Task.Run` task would silently swallow exceptions:

```
Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), async () =>
{
  CoinList = await RestService.GetCoins();
  return true;
});
```